# How do I grab the text inside of a span tag in Python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having a devil of a time trying to get the text from a list of items on petango.com. Screenshot of html below
I load the page using selenium to let it load.  then grab it for a bs object

```
PetSoup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
```

I've tried:

```
ul_tag = PetSoup.findAll('div', {'class': 'group details-list'})
pet_details = [i.get_text() for i in ul_tag]
print(pet_details)
```

this gets me all of the items as one list object (I think) but I can't seem to parse it out so the I can assign variables to each item (e.g. Age:, Breed:, etc.)

```
['\n\nBreed: Chihuahua, Short Coat / Mix\nAge: 15y 5m Gender: Male\nColor: Black / Grey\nSpayed/Neutered: Yes\nSize: Small\nDeclawed: No\nAdoption Date: \n\n']
```

I've also tried:

```
for ultag in PetSoup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'group details-list'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        print(litag.text)
```

which gets me all of the text, but again, can't seem to parse it to be able to assign variables

What I really want to do is just grab the text in the span tag but I can't seem to grab it.  I think it has something to do with how the span tag is structured, but I can't seem to get it by trying different variations of items in the span.  I just get an empty return.  The specific span is:

```
<span data-bind="text: breed">Terrier, Rat / Mix </span>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you for your help!
the specific page is here:
https://www.petango.com/Adopt/Dog-Terrier-Rat-22192827

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgRw0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract text from the span tag, simply use `span.text`. Here is how I extracted the span text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span data-bind="text: breed">Terrier, Rat / Mix </span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

span = soup.find('span')

print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
Terrier, Rat / Mix
```

This works fine. But I went a step further to scrape all the data from the website. Here is the full code to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.petango.com/Adopt/Dog-Terrier-Rat-22192827')

html = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

ul = soup.find('div',class_ = 'group details-list').ul #Gets the ul tag

li_items = ul.find_all('li') #Finds all the li tags within the ul tag

headings = []
values = []

for li in li_items:
    heading = li.strong.text
    headings.append(heading)
    
    value = li.span.text
    
    if value:
        values.append(value)
    else:
        values.append(None)
```

U can also create a beautiful `Pandas DataFrame` with these lists (for better readability) by adding these lines to the code:

```
details_dict = {'Headings':headings,
                'Values':values}

df = pd.DataFrame(details_dict)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Headings              Values
0            Breed:  Terrier, Rat / Mix
1              Age:              11y 7m
2            Color:       White / Black
3  Spayed/Neutered:                 Yes
4             Size:               Small
5         Declawed:                  No
6    Adoption Date:                None
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  That is exactly what I was trying to do!  I grabbed the list of pet detail url's from the first screen and was working on gathering all the data points from there and adding to lists but was STUCK on that item.  again, HUGE thank you!

Comment: YW! A humble request from my side. Could u pls upvote my answer?

Comment: I need 2 more reputation points to do, dah.....I got some for having the question upvoted...as soon as I get over the 15 mark will do for sure.  sorry for not being able to do faster

Comment: It's fine. Do it when u reach 15 reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution without `selenium`:

```
import re
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.petango.com/Adopt/Dog-Terrier-Rat-22192827'
ajax_url = 'https://www.petango.com/DesktopModules/Pethealth.Petango/Pethealth.Petango.DnnModules.AnimalDetails/API/Main/GetAnimalDetails?moduleId={}&animalId={}&clientZip=null'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

animal_id = url.split('-')[-1]
module_id = soup.select_one('[id^="Module-"]:has(.pet-id)')['id'].split('-')[-1]
tab_id = re.search(r'`sf_tabId`:`(\d+)`', html_text).group(1)

headers['TabId'] = tab_id
data = json.loads( requests.get(ajax_url.format(module_id, animal_id), headers=headers).text ) 

# print data to screen:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "id": 22192827,
    "speciesId": 1,
    "species": "Dog",
    "name": "Charlie 3",
    "photo": "https://g.petango.com/photos/1488/6955fc68-7a2e-4da1-af34-930c5fabd713.jpg",
    "photo2": "https://g.petango.com/photos/1488/450f6d7d-e501-475c-9b1f-9322dbc225eb.jpg",
    "photo3": "https://g.petango.com/photos/1488/4fbdbf1e-58b0-45c8-8c12-b5122ad1fff8.jpg",
    "youtubeVideoId": null,
    "age": "11y 7m",
    "distance": 0,
    "gender": "Male",
    "breed": "Terrier, Rat / Mix",
    "color": "White / Black",
    "spayedNeutered": "Yes",
    "size": "Small",
    "memo": null,
    "noDogs": false,
    "noCats": false,
    "noKids": false,
    "addToFavorites": false,
    "removeFromFavorites": false,
    "adoptionDate": null,
    "declawed": false,
    "adoptionApplicationUrl": "https://www.petango.com/Adoption-Application?shelterId=1897&animalId=22192827",
    "shelterName": "OH",
    "shelterCityState": "CINCINNATI, OH"
}
```